fixed number of columns (characters) per line in notepad++
I tried to follow the procedure here
Code length limiter in Notepad++
but I have version 8.6.8 and the menu
settings > preferences
looks different:

Neither in Editing 1 or Editing 2, I can find the option to change the column width or enabling the optional "show vertical edge".
Where can I change this?

For newer version of Notepad++:

Go to Settings -> Preferences -> Margins/Borders/Edge.
On the Vertical Edge Settings box, set the number of characters per column.


This is how the page will appear after settings the vertical edges per column.


I can't find the option to enable "show vertical edge".
In the latest version of Notepad++ (8.6.8) you need to go to Preferences > Margins/Border/Edge and change "Vertical Edge Settings:



I have set it to 80:




Further Reading

Preferences | Notepad++ User Manual


Is there also a way to automatically do a line break once the 80 characters are reached?
